# Ruby on Rails 4 - how to set background image in CSS from an external image path?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, background-image

I'm using Twilio to accept MMS messages and in my Rails app, when I retrieve the media, it comes in the form of a URL that looks something like this:

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe874e4bf40ad/Messages/MM301789b0623c042685/Media/MEf680190bd549cb9abe4adc5bb (note that this isn't an actual url, but is in the same form)

In my rails app, I'm trying to use css to set the background of a page to this url.

I have the following:

```
  body {
width: 6.25in;
height: 4.25in;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
/* your background image should have dimensions of 1875x1275 pixels. */
background-image: url('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACe874e4bf40ad/Messages/MM301789b0623c042685/Media/MEf680190bd549cb9abe4adc5bb');
background-size: 6.25in 4.25in;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

But this is not working.

Any thoughts on if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Make sure the css is syntactically correct and not escaped by Rails in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is no image on specified `background-image` url.

it is like below :
background-image:url("http://iconshow.me/media/images/Mixed/small-n-flat-icon/png/512/user-group.png");

Comment: with twilio, we receive urls in the format that seen above. In Rails, how would I go about taking that image url and turning it into one that has a jpg, png, etc extention?

Answer (score 0):

MMS messages may contain multiple images. Is the URL referencing one specific image? From [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request):

> Since there can be up to 10 images in one MMS, the "MediaUrl" parameter is structured as "MediaUrl0", "MediaUrl1" , "MediaUrl2" and etc.

From the [API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media) it seems you might be able to append ".jpg" or ".png" to the URL.

Comment: we're definitely getting a url that is an image and it's a single image. I can copy and paste the url into another tab and see it.

Comment: Updated - you might be able to append the file extension